# Iptable does not drop incoming or out going packets

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm using CentOS.

I have done the following in my IPTable test environment. I have flushed all the rules, using

```
    iptables -F
```

Then I have added the following rule.

```
    iptables -I INPUT -p all -j ACCEPT
```

Then based on an observation, I have added the this rule;

```
    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.50 -j DROP
```

I have run the

```
    service iptable save
```

After that i tried to ping the blocked ip (192.168.2.50). I can still ping it and the blocked ip can ping me.

I want to block any incomming connection from blocked IP.

This is my output for **iptables -L**

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP) target prot opt source destination

    ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
    DROP all -- 192.168.2.50 anywhere

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP) target prot opt source destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target prot opt source destination

    Chain icmp_packets (0 references) target prot opt source destination

    Chain tcp_packets (0 references) target prot opt source destination
```

Please help.. Thanks..

Comment: do you have multiple interfaces?

Comment: no. only one 1. eth0 interface only. What will be the difference if I have multiple interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iptables works with chains of rules. Inside a chain, rules are applied to packets in order, from the first (at the top) to the last.
Your first rule `ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere` let all the packets going through the chain to be accepted, so they don't go further to the next rule which should drop all.
Thus, if you want just to drop ALL the traffic to your macchine, just remove your first rule with `iptables -D INPUT 1` which will delete the first rule in the input chain, leaving only the drop all rule. Then add again the accept all rule with `iptables -A INPUT -p all -j ACCEPT`, so all the packets that are not from the blocked ip will be allowed to pass.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do 
`iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.50 -j DROP`
before `iptables -I INPUT -p all -j ACCEPT`.